# Variable size for input parameter array

Tags: openmdao

To give you a bit of a background, I am trying to maximize the total coverage by a satellite constellation. So what I basically do is estimate the initial state vector for every satellite, propagate them over a period of time and co-relate the area covered with my area of interest and estimate the coverage. The initial state vector is an array of 6 elements (3 position + 3 velocity). So if I have 2 satellites then the array will have 2 rows and 6 columns. The below simple test script mimics the same data flow and formulation of my actual code to calculate the initial position.

```python
import openmdao.api as om
import numpy as np

class InitialState(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def __init__(self, Nd):
        super(InitialState, self).__init__()
        self.Nd = Nd
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('a', val=120.456)
        self.add_input('b', val=58)
        self.add_input('c', val=46)
        self.add_input('d', val=np.zeros(self.Nd))

        self.add_output('rv0', val=np.zeros([self.Nd,6]))

        #self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='fd')
        self.declare_partials('*', '*')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        d = inputs['d']
        rv0 = np.zeros([len(d),6])
        for i in range(len(d)):
            r0, v0 = self.calc(inputs['a'], inputs['b'],
                                         inputs['c'], d[i])

            rv0[i,:3] = r0
            rv0[i,3:] = v0

        outputs['rv0']  = rv0.real 
    
    def calc(self, a, b, c, d):
        r0 = np.array([a**2,b*c*d,0],dtype=complex)
        v0 = np.array([d**2,a*b,0],dtype=complex)
        return r0,v0

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, J):
        h = 1e-16
        ih = complex(0, h)
        rv_drn = np.zeros(4,complex)
        Jacs = np.zeros((6, 4))

        for j in range(len(inputs['d'])):
            rv_drn[:] = [inputs['a'], inputs['b'], inputs['c'], inputs['d'][j]]
            start = j*6
            stop = start+6
            for i in range(4):
                rv_drn[i] += ih
                r0, v0 = self.calc(rv_drn[0], rv_drn[1], rv_drn[2], rv_drn[3])
                rv_drn[i] -= ih
                Jacs[:3, i] = r0.imag/h
                Jacs[3:, i] = v0.imag/h

            J['rv0', 'a'][start:stop] = [[k] for k in Jacs[:, 0]]
            J['rv0', 'b'][start:stop] = [[k] for k in Jacs[:, 1]]
            J['rv0', 'c'][start:stop] = [[k] for k in Jacs[:, 2]]
            J['rv0', 'd'][start:stop] = [[k] for k in Jacs[:, 3]]


model = om.Group()
Nd = 2
ivc = model.add_subsystem('ivc', om.IndepVarComp(), promotes_outputs=['*'])
ivc.add_output('a', val=120.456)
ivc.add_output('b', val=58)
ivc.add_output('c', val=46)
ivc.add_output('d', val=np.zeros(Nd))

model.add_subsystem('Pos', InitialState(Nd))

model.connect('a', 'Pos.a')
model.connect('b', 'Pos.b')
model.connect('c', 'Pos.c')
model.connect('d', 'Pos.d')

prob= om.Problem(model)
prob.setup()
prob['d'] = np.random.randint(10, size=(Nd))
prob.check_partials(compact_print=True)
prob.run_model()
print(prob['Pos.rv0'])
```

This code works as intended. The shape of `d`(phase angle) and `rv0` depend on `Nd`. Now to optimize this I will have to consider `Nd` (number of satellites) as a design variable (i.e declare it as ivc and have an other component or execcomp to calculate `d`). This however gives me an error as the shape of parameters cannot change after `setup()` . Is there a workaround for this ? I could calculate the position (and with it the coverage) for every single satellite by doing the model and problem setup inside a for loop and combine them in the end. But then again how can I access `Nd` (for the `for loop`) and make coverage the objective.

Edit: Now that I think about this, I do know the maximum value `Nd` can be and I could use this define the shape of the parameters. For example if max is 10 the I would define `rv0` as `self.add_output('rv0', val=np.zeros([10,6]))`. So if `Nd` is 2 in a iteration then `outputs['rv0'][:2,:]  = rv0.real`. The rest will be zero. I dont think this will have any impact on the overall coverage. But from Openmdao point will this cause any issue, that I dont see ? Or Is there a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic options:

1. Make the number of satellites an argument to your group, and allocate the correct sized arrays. Then run a separate optimization for each value of N and pick the one you like the best.
2. Allocate the arrays for the maximum possible number of satellites you want to consider, and add an additional blanking array as an input to turn certain ones on and off. Then you can use either a mixed integer approach or try some relaxation based approaches and treat the blanking array as real numbers.

I would personally chose option 2 for a couple of reasons. I would think the relaxation based approach would be more effective for larger numbers of N (MINLP are very hard to solve well). Also, its the most flexible approach, since you don't need to re-allocate anything. You can just adjust the values of the `active` array accordingly and turn things on an off at will.

Here is some updated code where you can do either method:

```
import numpy as np

class InitialState(om.ExplicitComponent):


    def initialize(self): 

        self.options.declare('max_Nd', default=10, types=int, 
                             desc='maximum number of allowed satellites')
    
    def setup(self):

        Nd = self.options['max_Nd']

        self.add_input('a', val=120.456)
        self.add_input('b', val=58)
        self.add_input('c', val=46)
        self.add_input('d', val=np.zeros(Nd))

        self.add_input('active', val=np.zeros(Nd)) # range from 0 to 1 to activate or de-activate

        self.add_output('rv0', val=np.zeros([Nd,6]))

        #self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*', method='fd')
        self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='cs')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        Nd = self.options['max_Nd']
        a = inputs['a']
        b = inputs['b']
        c = inputs['c']
        d = inputs['d']
        active = inputs['active']

        for i in range(Nd):
            outputs['rv0'][i,:3]  = [a**2,b*c*d[i],0] 
            outputs['rv0'][i,3:] = [d[i]**2,a*b,0] 

            outputs['rv0'][i,:] *= active[i]

model = om.Group()
Nd = 4
ivc = model.add_subsystem('ivc', om.IndepVarComp(), promotes_outputs=['*'],)
ivc.add_output('a', val=120.456)
ivc.add_output('b', val=58)
ivc.add_output('c', val=46)
ivc.add_output('d', val=np.zeros(Nd))
ivc.add_output('active', val=np.zeros(Nd))

model.add_subsystem('Pos', InitialState(max_Nd = Nd))

model.connect('a', 'Pos.a')
model.connect('b', 'Pos.b')
model.connect('c', 'Pos.c')
model.connect('d', 'Pos.d')
model.connect('active', 'Pos.active')

prob= om.Problem(model)
prob.setup()
prob['d'] = np.random.randint(10, size=(Nd))
prob['active'] = np.round(np.random.random(Nd))
prob.run_model()
print(prob['Pos.rv0'])
```

Comment: Hello. I am reading about MINLP and this is the perfect example I was searching for. Using a blanking array is a neat solution. But I am confused with your point 2. Let's say I am using integrality relaxation. Now a NLP optimizer picks `N =2.2`, I round off in a `execcomp` and `active = [1 1 0 0]`. Is my understanding correct? If so what do you mean by 'treat the blanking array as real numbers' , isn't it a binary array? And will this relaxation make the code inefficient ? Also is there a MINLP optimizer in openmdao ? If no, how to use a mixed integer approach ?

Comment: When you relax integrality, you are explicitly allowing N=2.2. You can't use a rounding function, since thats non-differentiable. You have to either accept a solution with non integer active values, or you need to use some kind of penalty method that will help drive the solution toward integer results. You can look into topology optimimzation approaches called SIMP and RAMP for examples.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I read about SIMP and RAMP. I do understand the logic but I have no clue how to apply it for this problem  or anyother problem as I couldn't find any examples. I managed to find some examples for interger programming and tried solving them in openmdao with penalty approach. I have some question about it and made a post. I will be grateful if you had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62944419/integer-programming-in-openmdao).